# How to get sum of 'payments' per day in rage of last 30 days in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have **'amount'** row in the payment database and I want to return sum of all payments per day in the last 30 days but i got stuck a little bit.  [This is what im expecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkXFb.png)

```
    $start = Carbon::now()->addDays(-30);
    $end = Carbon::now();

    $paymentslast30days = Payment::where('payment_date','<', $end)->where('payment_date','>',$start)->get();


    $days = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30];

    foreach($days as $day)
    {
     $day_date = $start->addDays($day-1);
     $number_of_payment_in_day = $paymentslast30days->where('payment_date',$day_date)->count();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here's the docs regarding grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#grouping).

```php
Payment::groupBy('payment_date')
    ->selectRaw('payment_date, SUM(amount)')
    ->whereRaw('payment_date >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
    ->orderByDesc('payment_date')
```

Two things:

- I'm not sure what your `amount` field is called
- the `where` clause for the date is MySQL-syntax, you may have to tweak this for different database engines